# Easier way to declare a lot of Views

Tags: android, view

I'm trying to build a timetable app and there I will need a lot of dynamical Textviews, the only way I know is to declare every Textview for it self like

```
    MoFa1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa1);
    MoFa2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa2);
    MoFa3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa3);
    MoFa4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa4);
    MoFa5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa5);
    MoFa6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa6);
    MoFa7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa7);
    MoFa8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa8);
    MoFa9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa9);
    MoFa10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoFa10);
```

Now I want to know if there is another easier way to declare multiple views.Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on how you are using them maybe an `array` of `TextView` and a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how they are displayed, but you could use a gridlayout and add them dynamically by looping throught cells.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2014/09/insert-view-to-gridlayout-dynamically.html?m=1

If these links actually help you, I will describe its content here.

Comment: can I put two Textviews in one griditem?

Comment: Yes you can put more than a View in a cell

Answer (score 2):

How are your views displayed? Since you're creating a timetable I think your views are displayed in a grid. You can use [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or you can use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) its an excellent article about using RecyclerView.

EDIT: [Here](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html) its another article using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Comment: I put them in a table

Answer (score 0):

Use butter knife http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

```
@BindView(R.id.MoFa5) TextView mofa5;
```

That's it. No findviewbyid.